# Complex conditional in PHP

Tags: php

I need to perform a redirect if user comes from another address than bonaca... or if he typed another pass than 1405 or 999.

The following code is not working properly.

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if (!(preg_match("/bonaca.net46.net/",$referrer))
or
!($_POST['pass'] == 1405
or
!$_POST['pass'] == 999)

 {
      header('Location: index.php');
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Not a preg_match, or (1405 or not 999)

Comment: @PezCuckow, if user comes from another address than `bonaca...` or if he typed another pass than `1405` or another pass than `999` he should be redirected.

Comment: @PezCuckow, Pez, I got `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'... on line 6` This is in fact line 5 here because the first line is opened php tag

Answer (score 1):

From http://php.net/preg_match

> Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster.

Based on your comment: The following will be true if the referrer does not contain `bonaca.net46.net` or the password is anything other than 1405 or 999

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if (strpos($referrer, "bonaca.net46.net") === FALSE
    || !($_POST['pass'] == 1405 || $_POST['pass'] == 999)
   )
{
      header('Location: index.php');

};
```

Comment: That's good advice but doesn't really answer the question though.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a few temporary variables to make the condition less bloated:

```
$userFromBonaca = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && strcasecmp(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST) , 'bonaca.net46.net') == 0;
$validPass = isset($_POST['pass']) && in_array($_POST['pass'], [1405, 999]);

if (!($userFromBonaca || $validPass)) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```